# Why is the Range of SwiftUI's ForEach loop not updating?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to display a list of items in a subview (`ListView`) inside `ContainerView` whenever the value of the array of those items is not `nil`. Every time the array is updated a new `ListView` should be displayed replacing the previous or be removed if the array is `nil`. The issue is that `ListView` seems to be displayed, removed and updated correctly except for the `ForEach` loop. It uses the same range every time eventhough a new `ListView` seems to be displayed.

I've created a simple example to demonstrate the issue. This is the `ContainerView`:

```
struct ContainerView: View {

    @State private var items: [Int]?
    private var listView: some View {
        items.map { ListView(items: $0) }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Display new List") { self.items = self.randomItems() }
            listView
        }
    }

    private func randomItems() -> [Int] {...}
}
```

This is the `ListView`:

```
struct ListView: View {

    private let randomInt: Int
    private let items: [Int]

    init(randomInt: Int = Int.random(in: 100 ..< 999), items: [Int]) {
        self.randomInt = randomInt
        self.items = items
        print("init | items: \(items)")
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
            Text("\(randomInt)")
            ForEach(0 ..< items.count) { index -> Text? in
                print("ForEach | index: \(index) items.count: \(self.items.count)")
                return self.items.count > index ? Text("\(self.items[index])") : nil
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When running this and tapping the "Display new List" button several times it will print something like this:

```
init | items: [0, 1, 2]
ForEach | index: 0 items.count: 3
ForEach | index: 1 items.count: 3
ForEach | index: 2 items.count: 3
init | items: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
ForEach | index: 0 items.count: 9
ForEach | index: 1 items.count: 9
ForEach | index: 2 items.count: 9
init | items: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
ForEach | index: 0 items.count: 6
ForEach | index: 1 items.count: 6
ForEach | index: 2 items.count: 6
```

So apparently a new `ListView` is created and on the device you also see that the correct `randomInt` is displayed, but for some reason `ForEach` is using the same range every time no matter how long the new array is.

Why is the range not updating or how can I force it to update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SwiftUI backend optimises views rendering and does not recreate view if thinks that it is equal, so it needs to inform that view differs.

The following fixes described issue. (Tested with Xcode 11.4beta3 / iOS 13.3)

```
private var listView: some View {
    items.map { ListView1(items: $0).id($0.count) }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
extension ForEach where Data == Range<Int>, ID == Int, Content : View {

    /// Creates an instance that computes views on demand over a *constant*
    /// range.
    ///
    /// This instance only reads the initial value of `data` and so it does not
    /// need to identify views across updates.
    ///
    /// To compute views on demand over a dynamic range use
    /// `ForEach(_:id:content:)`.
    public init(_ data: Range<Int>, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Int) -> Content)
}
```

> **To compute views on demand over a dynamic range use**
>   `ForEach(_:id:content:)`

Comment: I know about this, but I don't actually want the `ListView` itself to update so the data in this case is constant. I want to display a completely new `ListView` whenever the data changes.

Comment: ??? sorry, I don't understand. can you explain what do you expect?